# How to know selected spinner id in android creating programmatically

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have 6 spinners , create from dynamically.

```
List<Spinner>listSpinner        = new ArrayList<Spinner>();
Spinner sp;
for(int i;0;i<6; i++)
{
   sp= new Spinner(this);
   sp.setId(i);
// load data on spinner
  listSpinner.add(sp);  
}
```

Now my concern is, how to know particular id of clicked spinner.

if i click third spinner how to get of that spinner.
i try this:

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1, int pos, long id) {

                                for (int d = 0; d < listSpinner.size(); d++){

                                    if (listSpinner.get(d).getId()==(id)){ // i am not clear about id

                                        spinnerString =listSpinner.get(d).getSelectedItem().toString();
                                        Log.i("SPINN", "Selected Spinner value=" + spinnerString );

                                     }
                                    }
                                return;


                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                            }
                        });
```

but could get id of spinner, not spinner items.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
for (int d = 0; d < listSpinner.size(); d++)
{
   Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(listSpinner.get(d));
   Log.i("SPINN", "Selected Spinner value=" + s.getSelectedItem().toString() );
}
```

The point is, you need to call `findViewById`, using the `id` in your `listSpinner` before getting the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

For getting id of selected spinner inside onItemSelected, try this

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1,
                    int pos, long id) {

                for (int d = 0; d < listSpinner.size(); d++){

                                if (listSpinner.get(d).getId()==parent.getId()){ // parent.getId() returns the id of selected spinner

                                  // your code here

                                 }
                                }
                return;

            }
```